# 2 Fixed div , Problem with positioning in another divs

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have 3 div.

```
<div class="main"></div>
<div id="fixedbox"></div>
<div id="fixedBar"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {

width: 850px;
padding:25px 5px;
border-left:1px solid #999;
border-right:1px solid #999;
text-align:left;
overflow:hidden;
 }

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
body #fixedbox {
    position:fixed !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 865px;
    top: 0;
    width: 160px;
}
#fixedBar {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#F00;
}
* html #fixedBar {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Problem is this:
When Im adding a block with "`position:relative`" in main div, the block will move in scroll in ie. With adding  "`position:relative`" to body or main, there is other problems in ie. How can I used positions without problems in "`<div class="main"></div>`" ?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I have solved the problem with change the doctype.

Comment: This CDATA thingy is not needed since Mosaic 0.1 alpha... or something like that... `:)`

Comment: @Šime Vidas, you are right. I have removed this.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are adding position:relative to the body to position the 2 fixed position:absolute containers? If not you will need to.

I have had some problems with setting position:relative in IE in the past. Try some of the usual hacks like setting

```
height:1%;
```

Or

```
display:block;
```

to **.main**

You may find a specific solution on http://www.positioniseverything.net

Comment: body is not absolute, and I cant set position:relative to any block in main div. problems in ie6 ...., thanks steph.